# How to create a Browse button in android to load any image from sdcard

Tags: android

How to create a Browse button in android to load any image from SdCard?
Only the validated extension files must be allowed to open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like below. Put below code inside your button click event.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
```

so your full code will look something like this

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1))
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                                "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Hi @InnocentKiller, this code works well for me. Thanks.

Comment: @AjayBakshi, Glad to help you, and thank you for accepting my answer. +1 to you as well. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create button in xml,
2. In onClick listener of button, call openGallery() as below

.

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        openGallery();
    }
});

private void openGallery() {
    Log.v(TAG, "openGallery");
    Intent intent = new Intent();
            //shows all image files in device
    intent.setType("image/jpg"); 
            // or you can use intent.setType("image/*"); to open all image files.
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
            1);
}


// To handle when an image is selected from the browser, add the following
// to your Activity
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            // currImageURI is the global variable I'm using to hold the
            // content:// URI of the image
            currImageURI = data.getData();
                        final String imgpath = getRealPathFromURI(currImageURI);
                            //TODO: Got the image file path Do your stuff here
        }
    }
```

}